# if str.contains() condition on a dataframe's content; AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def store_press_release_links(all_sublinks_df, column_names):
    all_press_release_links_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
    for i in range(len(all_sublinks_df)):
            if (len(all_sublinks_df.loc[i,'sub_link'].str.contains('press|releases|Press|Releases|PRESS|RELEASES'))>0):
                all_press_release_links_df.loc[i, 'link'] = all_sublinks_df[i,'link']
                all_press_release_links_df.loc[i, 'sub_link'] = all_sublinks_df[i,'sublink']
            else:
                continue
          
    all_press_release_links_df = all_press_release_links_df.drop_duplicates()
    all_press_release_links_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return all_press_release_links_df
```

store_press_release_links() is  a function that accepts a dataframe, all_sublinks_DF, which has two columns. 1. link 2. sub_link
The contents of both these columns are iink names.
I want to look through all the link names present in the sub_link column of the all_sublinks_DF Dataframe  one by one and check if the link has the keywords ' press|releases|Press|Releases|PRESS|RELEASES' in it.
If it does, then I want to store that entire row of the all_sublinks_DF Dataframe to a new dataframe all_press_release_links_df.
But when I run this function it gives the error : **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'**

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: all_sublinks_df.loc[i,'sub_link'] apparently returns a str. So just call contains() on it -> just omit ‚str.‘

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do, instead of the loop just use

```py
all_press_release_links_df = all_sublinks_df[all_sublinks_df['sub_link'].str.contains('press|releases|Press|Releases|PRESS|RELEASES')]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong here. There are almost no situations where you want to loop through a pandas dataframe and equally there are almost no situations where you want to build a pandas dataframe row by row.

Here, the entire operation can be done with a single operation (split on two lines for readability) like such:

```
def store_press_release_links(all_sublinks_df):
    check_str = 'press|releases|Press|Releases|PRESS|RELEASES'
    return all_sublinks_df[all_sublinks_df.link.str.contains(check_str)]
```

The reason why you had the error message you had is because you select individual cells of the dataframe, which are not of type pandas.Series. The str property is a pd.Series property.

Also note how the columns field is no longer needed.